# EF Core Linq query with grouping: Why does DefaultIfEmpty() not work here?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, left-join, grouping

I have two tables that I'm trying to group with the [EF Core equivalent of a Left Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators). Table "Orders" lists the total amount of orders placed for a given item in each month of the year:

```
     ITEM     |     JANUARY     |     FEBRUARY     |     MARCH     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     Item A         $5,000            $3,000             $6,000
     Item B         $1,000            $4,000             $5,000
     Item C         $7,000            $9,000             $2,000
```

Table "Categories" lists the items on offer:

```
     ITEM     
--------------
     Item A   
     Item B
     Item C
     Item D
```

I'm trying to join the two lists into a single output table, where all the items from "Categories" are listed along with all the figures given in "Orders", if any. A month column should show "$0" if no orders for the item were placed that month, or zeroes across the board if the item doesn't appear in the Orders table at all:

```
     ITEM     |     JANUARY     |     FEBRUARY     |     MARCH     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     Item A         $5,000            $3,000             $6,000
     Item B         $1,000            $4,000             $5,000
     Item C         $7,000            $9,000             $2,000
     Item D         $0                $0                 $0
```

My ef core linq query is below, linking Orders to Categories on the Item column. Per the MS documentation linked above, I'm selecting from the grouping using ".DefaultIfEmpty()", since I still want Item D to appear in my list even if it does not appear in the Orders table.

```
var output = (from c in categories 
                join o in orders on c.item equals o.item into grouping
                from b in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new Output_Model
                {
                    product = c.product,
                    January = b.January,
                    February = b.February,
                    March = b.March,
                    April = b.April,
                    May = b.May,
                    June = b.June,
                    July = b.July,
                    August = b.August,
                    September = b.September,
                    October = b.October,
                    November = b.November,
                    December = b.December
                }).ToList();
```

However, when the query gets to Item D, the process fails with the "Object reference not set" error, and the monthly values throwing a System.NullReferenceException. I thought ".DefaultIfEmpty()" was supposed to handle this sort of thing? The month columns in Output_Model are set as nullable.

If I alter my query so that "Categories" is joined on "Orders" with the same criteria, the process completes successfully, but "Item D" is not included in the list. How can I get this working?

Comment: Did you try  `January = b != null ? b.January : 0,`

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NavoneelTalukdar for this one.

It turned out I need to handle my nullities individually, so after I added null handling to each item in the query, I got the results I was looking for.

```cs
var output = (from c in categories 
                join o in orders on c.item equals o.item into grouping
                from b in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new 
                {
                    product = c.product,
                    January = b != null ? b.January : 0,
                    February = b != null ? b.February : 0,
                    March = b != null ? b.March : 0,
                    April = b != null ? b.April : 0,
                    May = b != null ? b.May : 0,
                    June = b != null ? b.June : 0,
                    July = b != null ? b.July : 0,
                    August = b != null ? b.August : 0,
                    September = b != null ? b.September : 0,
                    October = b != null ? b.October : 0,
                    November = b != null ? b.November : 0,
                    December = b != null ? b.December : 0
                }).ToList();
```